# anyone know how to test iPhone safari dimensions on an iPad? Is there an emulator app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, mobile-safari

I only have an iPad, but I'm working on an iPhone site and I need to test for its dimensions. Anyone know an app made for this?

Answer (score 1):

The iOS development tools, incl. Xcode, Interface Builder etc. have an iOS device simulator. You can download these tools from Apple if you're a registered (free) Apple developer.
(These run only on Mac OS X)

Comment: And only if you're using a Mac ;-)

Comment: yea, but I dont have a mac either (well i do--im actually referring to a developer of mine who has a PC and an iPad, but no iPhone)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a Mac, you could download a iPhone app which has a browser in built. 
Try installing Dolphin iPhone App on the iPad

Or on a Mac, you may test it on the iPhone Simulator.

1. Open iOS simulator,
2. Select iPhone in Hardware > Device
3. Open Safari on the simulator and type in your URL.

Comment: +1 for Dolphin - it's not universal, so will run as an iPhone app on the iPad

Answer (score 0):

Would an online simulator do?

http://iphone4simulator.com/ or http://transmog.net maybe?

Comment: na, the online simulators just aren't the same. close but not enough.